# How to split dataset into train and test when the number of samples do not match?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm working with PlantVillage dataset for an image classification model built with Keras, based on [this](https://www.kaggle.com/emmarex/plant-disease-detection-using-keras/notebook) example. I'm trying to divide the dataset into train and test. However, I have 1676 images and only 15 labels, each corresponding to the names of the folders containing the images. Here is the piece of code I'm working with:

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(np_image_list, image_labels, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
```

And the error I am getting:

```
 ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1676, 15]
```

Comment: you have to input X and y. both need to be same dimensions. you aren't using the number of different labels for y, but a label for each value in X

Comment: dimension wasn't really the right term. X and y have to be the same length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when the samples do not match then you need to concat them first. for example if you have train.csv with 100 columns including target label and test.csv with 99 columns then you need to remove the target label from train.csv and concat both train.csv and test.csv. Once you have merged both then you can split them with .iloc into your choice of samples for train and test datasets.

```
df = 200 columns
train = df.iloc[:100,:]
test = df.iloc[100:,:]
```